# Check if pandas dataframe contains specific string from a list of items

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a list

```
my_list = ['element1 line','element2 ','element3', 'element4 line',....]
```

and I have a pandas dataframe having `df`[`Sentences`] column and `df['flag']` column

```
df
    Sentences               flag
0   abcd    
1   efgh    
2   element1 ijkl           
3   mnop element3 element4      
4   qrst
```

I want to iterate to each and every row of dataframe of column `Sentences`. If any of the elements in my_list is present in the `Sentences`, `df['flag']` column should be 1 in the respective row. If no elements is present in the string of sentences in that row, `df['flag']` should be 0 for that row.

**Expected output:**

```
df
    Sentences                flag
0   abcd                      0
1   efgh                      0
2   element1 ijkl             1 
3   mnop element3 element4    1     
4   qrst                      0
```

Comment: 'element1 ijkl' does not exist in your list since your list contains 'element1 line' not 'element1'?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this without 2 for-loops:

```
df['flag'] = df['Sentences'].str.split().map(set).
                             apply(lambda x: any(x.intersection(my_list))*1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop:

```
df['flag'] = [int(any(w in my_list for w in x.split())) for x in df['Sentences']]
```

output:

```
                Sentences  flag
0                    abcd     0
1                    efgh     0
2           element1 ijkl     1
3  mnop element3 element4     1
4                    qrst     0
```

---

*Note that you could use pure pandas, but this is **much** slower:*

```
df['flag'] = (df['Sentences']
              .str.split()
              .explode().isin(my_list)
              .groupby(level=0).any().astype(int)
              )
```

Comment: @user16345032 not with the provided example (I checked it), please edit the question to provide the output of: `df.head().to_dict('list')`